# Elasticsearch - Enum datatype

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I want to store documents like the one below:

```
{
  "item_id": 1,
  "item_price": 500,
  "currency": "USD"
}
```

I want the currency field to be like ENUM, so I can predefine the set of values, like: "USD", "GBP", "EUR" and so on...

I also would like that each value will be related to an integer, like hash map, so the set of values will look like this:

```
{ "USD":1, "GBP":2, "EUR":3 }
```

how shell I map this field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare your enum in your indexing code and your document should be denormalized like this:

```
{
  "item_id": 1,
  "item_price": 500,
  "currency": "USD",
  "currency_id": 1
}
```

As for the data types, I suggest to declare the `currency` field as `keyword` and the `currency_id` field as `byte` or `short` depending on the number of currencies you need to track.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But can I define a set of currencies (strings) in advance, so if I'll enter wrong currency which is not in the set ("USF" for example) elasticsearch will recognize my mistake? and another thing, according to you example I can by mistake enter "USD" with id of 2.

Comment: ES has a typing system and allows you to define mapping types, but doesn't make the kind of checks you're describing. It is up to you to make sure your indexing code is sound and consistent. Unit-test it ;-)

Comment: OK, So what are the benefits for making this field `keyword` type instead of `string` type.

Comment: It will not be analyzed, so you can run aggregations on it. if that's intended to be an enum, it doesn't really make sense to be anything else than a `keyword`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `keyword` data type, it's pretty efficient